# React JS - Material UI: Icons are not visible

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am using Material UI and my goal is to make an Icon button. Therefore I tried this:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import DoneOutlineSharpIcon from '@material-ui/icons/DoneOutlineSharp';
import IconButton from '@material-ui/core/IconButton'

export class App extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <IconButton> <DoneOutlineSharpIcon style={{color: "green"}}/> </IconButton>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Additionally, I added the material icons to the index.html like this:

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icon‌​s" rel="stylesheet">
```

The Icon is not visible, but pressing F12 in the "Elements" it shows that there is a button.

I am still new to React, so I might have done something stupidly wrong. Can someone tell me what I missed here? And how can I simply place an Icon into a Button?

Comment: Thanks for the MRE! It looks [like this works](https://codesandbox.io/s/stack-debugging-materialui-gqkx8?file=/src/App.js), as least on CodeSandbox. From your src folder, have you run the commands `npm install @material-ui/core` and `npm install @material-ui/icons` ??

Comment: Yes I ran these commands. Thank you for this. I just found my stupid mistake which was that I wanted the background of the whole screen to be orange by typing ```* {
  background-color: orange;}``` in the App.css. Removing this command the icon was visible again. Btw what does MRE mean?

Comment: That's hilarious, funny how that stuff can get in the way sometimes. Oh and MRE means minimal reproducible example, it helps with debugging code.